# Why does select result fields double data scanned in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with 2 integer fields x,y and few millions of rows.
The fields are created with the following code:

```
Field.newBuilder("x", LegacySQLTypeName.INTEGER).setMode(Field.Mode.NULLABLE).build();
```

If I run the following from the web:

```
SELECT x,y FROM [myproject:Test.Test]  where  x=1 LIMIT 50
Query Editor: "Valid: This query will process 64.9 MB when run."
```

compared to:

```
SELECT x FROM [myproject:Test.Test]  where  x=1 LIMIT 50
Query Editor: " Valid: This query will process 32.4 MB when run."
```

It scans more than double of the original data scanned.
I would expect it will first find the relevant rows based on where clause and then bring the extra field without scanning the entire second field.

Any inputs on why it doubles the data scanned and how to avoid it will be appreciated.
In my application I have hundred of possible fields which I need to fetch for a very small number of rows (50) which answer the query.
Does this means I will need to processed all fields data?
* I'm aware how columnar database works, but wasn't aware for the huge price when you want to brings lots of fields based on a very specific where clause.

The following link provide very clear answer:
[best-practices-performance-input](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-input)

Comment: Have a read here: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on_demand_pricing _"BigQuery uses a columnar data structure. You're charged according to the total data processed in the columns you select, and the total data per column is calculated based on the types of data in the column"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery does not have a concept of index or something like that. When you query a field column, BigQuery will scan through all the values of that column and then make the operations you want (for a deeper deep understanding they have some pretty cool [posts](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2016/01/bigquery-under-the-hood) about the inner workings of BQ).

That means that when you select x and y where x = 1, BQ will read through all values of x and y and then find where x = 1.

This ends up being an amazing feature of BQ, you just load your data there and it just works. It does force you to be aware on how much data you retrieve from each query. Queries of the type `select * from table` should be used only if you really need all columns.